# Pantalla negra cuando paso de Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment

Al pulsar un botón el primer Fragment recupera información de un servidor, en algunos casos esta información tarda debido a la mala calidad de los enlaces. En el momento de la transición del primer al segundo Fragment la pantalla se pone negra.
Si el enlace funciona bien y recupera rápido la información esto no sucede.
¿Es posible agregar entre fragmentos un mensaje de espera?

Agrego codigo:

--snip--

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


if (mItem != null) {

     if (mItem.id.equals("1") || mItem.id.equals("2") || mItem.id.equals("6")) {

                con = new coneccion(); //Extends DialogFragment
                con.conectar(mContexto);
                conDeDatos = con.conectado();

                if (conDeDatos) {

                    if (mItem.id.equals("1")) { 
                        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.control_alarma, container, false);

                        //Enviá comando para recuperar estado svr remoto
                        enviar(Comandos.OP_ESTADO, "0", "");

                        //actualiza la vista del fragment
                        //estado es un array que se llena con cargarEstado(datos)
                        actualizarAlarma(estado);

                    }

}

return rootView;

}
```

--snip--

--snip--

```
private void enviar(String comando, String accion, String parametro) {

    String datos="";
    Boolean bandera = false;

con.enviarDatos(comando,accion,parametro);

                    if(con.sucess()){

                        try{
                            datos = con.getData();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            datos = Comandos.RET_ERROR_DESCONOCIDO;
                        }

                        Log.v("Data ",datos);

                        //Si no hay error de claves EK o Error de comando
                        if(!datos.equals(Comandos.RET_ERROR_COMANDO)
                                && !datos.equals(Comandos.RET_ERROR_CLAVES)
                                && !datos.equals(Comandos.RET_ERROR_VERSION_PROTO)) {

                            if (comando.equals(Comandos.OP_ESTADO) || comando.equals(Comandos.OP_ESTADO_LUCES)) { //Estado
                                bandera = true;
                                cargarEstado(datos);
                            }
```

--snip--

--snip--

```
private void actualizarAlarma(boolean estado[]){

    final Switch swArmar = (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swArmar);

    try {
        //estado es que se carga con  cargarEstado(datos);
        swArmar.setChecked(estado[0]);


    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    swArmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (swArmar.isChecked()) {
                enviar(Comandos.OP_ARMAR,"1","");
            } else {
                enviar(Comandos.OP_ARMAR,"0","");
            }
        }
    });
```

--snip--

En onCreateView establezco la conexión al **svr** si nos pudimos conectar envió un comando para poder sincronizar el estado.
El envió y la recepción es por dos metods AsyncTask en la clase coneccion().
La tarea asíncrona de recepción tiene un **time out** mínimo de 5 segundos. Es decir que cuando realizo el envió del comando de sincro con el svr, **si se demora la respuesta la pantalla se pone negra.**
He probado lanzar antes de enviar el comando y nada, también extendí la clase conexión con DialogFragment y nada. Ademas del pre y post Execute y nada me resulto satisfactorio, **todos son ejecutados al actualizarse el segundo fragment.** Me refiero a los diálogos o Barras de progreso.

Comment: la carga de datos hazlo con un asynctask, así no bloquearás la UI, puedes mostrar un ProgressDialog hasta que termine la tarea.

Comment: Todas las llamadas están hechas con AsyncTask, pero el segundo fragment depende de los datos retornados.

Comment: pues lanza un progressdialog al preExecute() y despues al postExecute() lo cierras, así mientras la tarea se este realizando el usuario verá el dialogo.
De paso también pon un poco de código para ver como tienes implementado la llamada del asynctask y el cambio de fragmento...